# Mac OS X Yosemite no stdarg.h file

Tags: c++, c, macos, compilation

XCode was installed normally and successfully as far as I can tell. However, there is no /usr/include/stdarg.h but there is /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdarg.h.

When I try to make file, I get

```
cannot find include file "stdarg.h"
not in ./stdarg.h
not in /usr/include/stdarg.h
```

Also, I think I properly installed the Command Line Tools for Xcode:

```
xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: I know this sounds daft, but the file is probably in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.1.0/include/`. Don't forget to use angle brackets (i.e., `#include <stdarg.h>`, not `#include "stdarg.h"`), and if that doesn't work, try adding XCode's include directory to your include path.

Comment: What are you trying to build here? It looks as though it's trying to search for header files on its own (i.e, without the compiler). This is strange and not recommended.